# Disable TableView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I disable all cells, except the first 3 cells of a UITableView?

This returns nil if one of the disabled cells is selected:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ( indexPath.row >= 3 ) {
    [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]] setAlpha:0.5];
    return nil;
}

return indexPath; }
```

**How can I make the disabled cells "visible"?**
This works, but I only on start up, because the indexPath of every cell changes while scrolling (reuse cells):

```
for(int i = 3; i <= 100; i++) {
    [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] setAlpha:0.5];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to set the opacity of the disabled cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. As @Parcs correctly says in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560829/839965), you can also set `userInteractionEnabled` for the disabled cells to NO there.

You can just ignore the taps on inactive cells in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Yes, this works fine when I newly start the application, but when I scroll down the indexPaths change (tableView recycles the cells) and all cells are disabled.

Comment: You only need to disable the cells for the specific indexPaths. Be sure to also explicitly enable the cells that should be enabled inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This will prevent the problem with the cell reuse that you're seeing.

Comment: I´m using this code inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` : `if ( indexPath.row >= 3 ) {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }`

Comment: Add an `else` block to this `if` statement and inside it set those two cell properties to their normal values.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear!

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the cells by setting the selectionStyle property, see the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

Another way to disable the cell selection is by disabling the user interaction of the cell. See the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = ...

        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    }
```

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Yes, this works fine when I newly start the application, but when I scroll down the indexPaths change (tableView recycles the cells) and all cells are disabled. –

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer providing code is outdated only showing how it's done in obj-c, here is a swift solution.
To disable a cell you need to set the `isUserInteractionEnabled` flag of a `UITableViewCell` to false.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // dequeue cell
    ...
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return cell
}
```

For subclasses of `UITableViewCell` you probably also want to alter the appearance of the now disabled cell. You can do so by overriding the property to run additional code when the flag gets set.

```swift
override var isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool {
    didSet {
        super.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUserInteractionEnabled
        // additional code to change text colors for example
    }
}
```